# How can i make clickable uiimage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have one menubar as a uiimage. I want to make 5 menu on this menubar are clickable and link to another view. Can anyone tell me the way i can do that? I found people using uibutton on the uiimage, Is that fine for me and how can i separate the menu bar to 5 pieces.

Thanks for both rmaddy and Brent Royal-Gordon

I decided to use the uiimage as a menubar background and add the uibutton on it. i try some thing like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                     pathForResource:@"MOVIE" ofType:@"MP4"]];

MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:moviePlayer];

moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
[moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,1330,320)];

[scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1330,320)];
[scrollView setScrollEnabled: YES];
[scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];

[scrollView addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:image.frame];   
UIImage *menubar = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BG.jpg"];
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:menubar];
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 258, imageView.frame.size.width, 25);
[self.view addSubview:imageView];

[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];   
[btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0,258,30,25)];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btn setTitle:@"HOME" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[imageView addSubview:btn];
```

but the button is not visible on screen when i run on the simulator. What did i do wrong?

Comment: your button was visible or not?

Comment: No, it's not visible. It just show the image that i add by using uiimageview

Comment: once change the width of the button and check it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand "change the width of the button". Can you give me some example?

Comment: set [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0,258,60,25)]; and test it.

Comment: It's also not visible.

Comment: i have checked with your code it's coming.

Comment: I use xcode 3.2.5. Is it support for this one? I tested it on simulator (ios 4.2)

Comment: I try to fix it by myself but the button still invisible, Can you help me? I have edited all my code above.

Answer (score 4):

Using a gesture recognizer is a bad idea because:

1. It forces you to interpret the touch areas for each submenu yourself.
2. It's opaque to VoiceOver.
3. It doesn't show a highlight when the user touches a button. These sorts of highlights help the user understand what the user interface is doing, so they're very valuable.

What you should do is split the single image into five in a graphics tool like Photoshop, and make each of these slices the `image` of a `UIButton`. You'll need to design highlighted states for these images (shown when one of them is held down), but you should be doing that anyway.

If you *must* slice the image in code, you can do that by using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0)` and drawing your big image using `drawAtPoint:` with an appropriate offset to get the slice you want, but 99.99999% of the time, it'll make more sense to slice the images once on your big, beefy, wall-plug-powered Mac than every time your app runs on a tiny, slow, battery-powered iOS device.

Comment: I separate as you said but i stuck on the button is not visible. Can you help me to fix it?

Comment: If you're creating the buttons in code, you'll want to call `-setImage:forState:` with `UIControlStateNormal` as the `state` parameter. If you're creating the buttons in Interface Builder, you should be able to set the image in the Attributes Inspector (slider icon) in the right-hand inspector sidebar.

Comment: I try to create it in the Interface builder but it seem the video hide the button

Comment: The menubar i created in the interface builder just coming up only few  seconds and then it disappear when i'm running the code

Comment: When you set the frame of `btn`, that frame's origin is relative to the top left corner of its superview, the `imageView`. So you're positioning `btn` 258px from the top of a 25px tall parent view. Suffice it to say, you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: I set that number because my app' orientation is landscape. what did i do wrong?

Comment: The problem is simply that you're applying that number twice. `btn` is a subview of `imageView`, so specifying an `origin.y` of 258 means it will be 258 px lower than the top of `imageView`. But `imageView` is *also* 258 px lower than the top of `self.view`, so `btn` ends up being 516 px from the top of `self.view`. That's probably further than you intended. If you want `btn` to be right at the top of `imageView` (and 258 px from the top of `self.view`), just make sure `btn`'s frame's `origin.y` is 0, not 258.

Comment: Although, i change the origin.y to 0, the button still invisible.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `UITapGestureRecognizer` with the `UIImageView` containing your image. You will need to set the `userInteractionEnabled` property to `YES` on the image view.

When you get the tap event, look at where in the view the tap occurred. Based on the location, perform one of the five menu actions.

If you want more control, you may be better off splitting the image into 5 and creating 5 `UIButton` instances instead.

Comment: if i use the UITapGestureRecognizer, how can i set the position of the tap gesture

Comment: You don't set the position of the tap gesture. You assign the tap gesture to the view. The tap gesture will tell you where in the view the tap occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Why you add it the buttons to image view ? Just adding it to the View. It will solve the problem(as i understand).

> [imageView addSubview:btn];

Try like this

> [self.view addSubview:btn];

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

issue is with the Width of the button.Try

this

> [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0,258,100,50)]

(increase width to 100)

and you may need to change the title colour if your background is white

> [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:
>   UIControlStateNormal];

Answer (score 0):

you Can first add button view then add imageview on the button please see bellow code :

//Add first button

UIButton *btnImage = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

```
btnImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 4, 60, 56);

btnImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:231.0f/255.0f green:232.0f/255.0f blue:234.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];

btnImage.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:183.0f/255.0f green:184.0f/255.0f blue:186.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0].CGColor;

btnImage.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;

// Add imageview on button 

UIImageView *yourImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
[yourImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"]];
yourImageView.center = CGPointMake(btnImage.frame.size.width/2, btnImage.frame.size.height/2);
[btnImage addSubview:yourImageView];

[self.view addSubview:btnImage];
```